# URI / Slug auto generation limitation

Tags: entries, url

Craft seems to have a limitation when generating unique URI for > 100 entries with the same title.....

I have a channel with YouTube videos in and some are spread across 140 parts all with the same title, and craft auto appends a -1 -2 etc. on the slug but fails when it reaches 3 digits.

Is there anyway to change this limitation?

At the moment it just responds with this:

```
Internal Server Error

Could not find a unique URI for this element.
```

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this we added a new config setting for the upcoming 2.2 release called `maxSlugIncrement`.

It defaults to 100, but you can bump it if you need it to keep finding more unique URIs.

Comment: Any chance of an update?

Comment: Oops... will update answer now.